# Changing HTML on only one page wordpress

Tags: php, html, database, wordpress

(I'm new to stackoverflow)I am trying to change only the home page on wordpress, not the page content, but I am trying to remove the content/body section all together, and put a full size video there instead. Since wordpress uses PHP I thought I could just view page source, then copy all the code then make an `index.html` file in my web root and delete the `index.php` file (I would prefer not to do it that way). Could this work? Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will not work with wordpress it relies on a fairly robust system of PHP templating. Aka, nothing else would work on your website and wordpress would not choose to load the index.html over the index.php due to server settings.

Instead, you must use a [code editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/code-editor/) plugin to change your theme in the PHP. This would mostly involve just changing the HTML templating and not really any PHP code depending on what you want to do. It should be fairly straightforward after using the plugin and activating the new theme from the admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

Why setup WordPress if you are not going to use its CMS features? And no, deleting the index.php and replacing it by index.html does not work.

What you could do is move WordPress entirely to for example yourdomain.com/home and make your WordPress website there. Place another index.html/index.php in your root directory with the video you want to display, although I would not recommend doing this.

Why don't you just place the video on the home page?

Can you maybe explain in a little more detail what exactly it is that you are trying to achieve with this website and separate home page? Maybe there is a better solution for your issue.

Comment: My theme that im using makes a little box with margins for its text, but I want to make a full page video on the home page once you scroll down. [this is my site](http://garrettalden.com)

Comment: Mind showing me the website? There a tons of other themes (for free as well) where you can make one-page websites will full screen photo's and video's.